# find open balls $B_1,B_2,B_3,\ldots$ so: $U=\bigcup _{n\in \Bbb N} B_n$ , where $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : y\gt x\}$

Tags: metric-spaces

> In the metric space $(\Bbb R^2,d_{\Bbb R^2})$: How can I find open balls $B_1,B_2,B_3,\ldots$   so:
>
> $U=\bigcup _{n\in \Bbb N} B_n$, where:
>
> $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : y\gt x\}$.
>
> and why it is not possible to do this for: $U'=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : y\ge x\}$.

Comment: Notice the edits I did on your question.  There is no need to set the $\{$curly braces$\}$ OUTSIDE of TeX, and when you do that, then spacing conventions may fail to be followed.

Comment: Thank u.. I am new to MathJax .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
  U = \bigcup_{x\in U\cap \mathbb Q} B(x;r_x)
$$
where
$$
r_x~=~ d(x,\partial U)
$$
is the distance between point $x$ and the line $\{(x,x):~x\in\mathbb R\}$. If you want uniformly bounded balls you may consider $r_x'=\min\{r_x,1\}$ as radiuses. In both cases the union is countable and entirely covers $U$. Since $B(x,r_x)\subseteq U$ for every $x\in U\cap \mathbb Q$, then the union is contained in $U$ and therefore the equality above holds.

The second set ($\overline U$) is closed, while unions of open balls is still open. The only sets which are both open and closed are $\mathbb R^2$ and $\emptyset$, so $\overline U$ cannot be expressed in such way. You may find a *covering*, but it will never coincide with $\overline U$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for $U'$, because $B_n$ is open for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and therefore $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ is open, too, whereas $U'$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.